# Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, web-config, connection-string

I try to connect to my database(which is recently moved to another server) with EF.

Server name is :SERVER-PC

Version of MSSQL : Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8

The instance name when I get it using xp_regread sp: MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER

I want to ad both instance name , and server name in connection string. 
this is my connectionstring which I got help from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms156450.aspx)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source= SERVER-PC\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=FoodDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but when I run the project , this error happens:

> error : {"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken
>   string."}
>
> An error occurred while getting provider information from the
>   database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect
>   connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure
>   that the connection string is correct.

Could anyone please give me a help?

*Note: I want to use both server name and Instance name (intentionally) in connection string. (assume the instance is not default)*

Comment: What connection string is stated at your DBContext? It should be something as following: public DbContext() : base("Name=DefaultConnectiont") { }

Comment: @AdilMammadov I did it exactly like that

Answer (score 0):

The EF unable to determine the SQL Server store version:

```
-- Get Server name
SELECT @@servername

-- Get service name
SELECT @@servicename
```

### MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER = instance Id and not name!

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source= .\; Initial Catalog=FoodDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source= SERVER-PC\; Initial Catalog=FoodDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Note: To connect to the default instance you don't specify the instance name, only the server name. 
 MSSQLSERVER  = default name

Comment: thank you for the reply. 
in terms of putting instance and servername in connection string , Actually I did it in purpose. I tried to use the instance name , because I wanted to check how can I use the connection string if there isn't default instance installed.Also I got the variables in connection string from @@servicename and  @@servername and the same error happened.

Comment: @SarahN You have the default instance name in Sql Server in this case you do not have to give any instance name this is the porblem. did you tried to set the instance name to .\   (in the connection string)

Comment: : I tried that. it worked . but I was just curious to put the instance and servername in connectonString